# Clip function in the sf package in R

Tags: r, clip, sf, intersect

I try to clip shape "a" with shape "b". The result should be a polygon with the attributes and borders of "a" but cliped on the extent of "b". Basically a simple clip as we know it from ArcMap or QField.
Now I want to use the `sf package` in R. But all the suggestions I find tell me to use````st_intersection```.
But this is not actually a clip because it will result in a layer containing also the borders of "b".

```
a<-st_read("a.shp")
be<-st_read("b.shp"
Clip1<- st_intersection(a,b)
```

What I want

[image: What I want]

what st_intersection does

[image: what st_intersect does]

Comment: What are the black dots in your diagram? Are the green, blue, and grey areas separate features?

Comment: There is no `st_intersect` function in `sf`. There's `st_intersects`, which tests for intersection, and there's `st_intersection`, which seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes they are separate features. My problem is, that a intersection preserves the feature boundaries of the intersect feature as you can see in the second image. I solved this problem now by using ```st_union``` on the intersect feature before the intersection. But it is odd that there is no command to do this directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This all works for me:

```
> library(sf)
> plot(input$geom, col=input$colour)
> plot(clip$geom, col=NA, border="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

```
> output = st_intersection(input, clip)
> plot(output$geom, col=output$colour)
```

[image]

The `output` object has the attributes from the underlying `input` object:

```
> output 
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 350715.5 ymin: 556199.3 xmax: 378850.3 ymax: 579962.8
CRS:            27700
  colour                       geometry
1  green POLYGON ((365346.3 579873.5...
2   grey POLYGON ((377844 569519.7, ...
3   blue POLYGON ((354933 574695.8, ...
>
```

Comment: Yes for your case this works. But if your "clip" layer consists of multiple features overlaying the "input" layer, these feature are as well integrated into the "output" layer. I found a solution to use ```st_union``` for the "clip" layer before the intersection.

Comment: This case is exactly the example of "what I want" from your question. You show the clip feature as a single feature. If you'd shown it as two semicircles then I'd have suggested unioning the clipping features.

Comment: You're right I replaced the images.

Comment: This is a good answer and I tried this, however, attributes of the layer that is clipped seem to get lost in the process?